# How do I build Jena Fuseki 2 from source?

Tags: jena, fuseki, apache-jena

I ran into a known issue with Jena Fuseki 2.0 where the default timeout is too small on UI created datasets. See http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.jena.user/6824. This issue is resolved under JENA-918.

I needed to get a build of Fuseki with the fix and resorted to cloning the repo:

git clone http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/jena.git

and doing a build:

mvn package

But I got this error...

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.11:check (rat-checks) on project jena-fuseki: Too many files with unapproved license: 1 See RAT report in: /home/sparqlycode/fuseki2/src/jena/jena-fuseki2/target/rat.txt -> [Help 1]

Should I have expected it to build or are there some build instructions I should have read?

Comment: That is what the daily build runs.  What is in the RAT report? Do you have other files in the directory?

Comment: @AndyS whoops. I had created a shell script to setup for Java 8. Such a dummy - should have read the rat.txt. Built now ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can expect mvn package to work without problems. It runs daily from this as @AndyS clearly says. In this case a file had been introduced by myself that did not have a license in its header so it was caught by RAT. Removing the file resolved the problem.